# How can I disable input from the laptop keyboard in (Kubuntu) Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, keyboard, kubuntu

I want to disable the laptop keyboard so that I can put a normal USB keyboard on top of it. Is there anyway to do it? I DON'T want to do it through X (i.e xinput float), because I need to be able to use the tty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the configuration file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and remove the keyboard.

Comment: Isn't that the same as 'xinput float' only more permanent? Also I want it to work even when there is **no X**.

Comment: My apologies, I thought that for some reason you didn't want to use the desktop application to disable it.